# Adding date to a vector of data

Tags: r, datetime

Im having a little trouble with R and adding a date to a vector of data. I guess i'm messing around with objects the wrong way?

Data: y (that is numeric[9])

```
y <-data.frame
y
temp     cons     wind      ror      solar   nuclear   chp       net    thermal  
0.5612   0.5065   0.1609   0.2989   0.7452   0.9621   0.2810   0.6998   0.4519
```

I want to add a column in at the start that contains todays date, so it will look like:

```
date           temp     cons     wind      ror      solar   nuclear   chp       net    thermal  
28-06-2013    0.5612   0.5065   0.1609   0.2989   0.7452   0.9621   0.2810   0.6998   0.4519
```

Im using Sys.Date()+1 to get the date of tomorrow, but when I cbind it with my data, I get some unwanted results, like:

```
tomorrow<-Sys.Date()+1
cbind(tomorrow, y)
vector      y
temp      15884 0.5612
cons      15884 0.5065
wind      15884 0.1609
ror       15884 0.2989
solar     15884 0.7452
nuclear   15884 0.9621
chp       15884 0.2810 
net       15884 0.6998
thermal   15884 0.4519
```

I don't want the date displayed in this numeric format, and im not quite sure why the data suddenly becomes a matrix variable.

Comment: Apparently `y` is not a data.frame. If you `cbind` two vectors you get a matrix and there can only be one data type in a matrix.

Comment: instead of use `cbind`, you can add it to the list with the $ operator, that's `y$date<- something`

Comment: add the output from `dput(head(y))` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a data.frame, you have a vector. You can append data to a vector like so:

```
y <- rnorm(10)
names(y) <- letters[1:10]
cbind(Sys.Date(), y) # vector, see?

                  y
a 15883 -1.21566678
b 15883  0.98836517
c 15883 -1.01564976
d 15883 -0.59483533
e 15883 -0.40890915
f 15883  1.69711341
g 15883  0.05012548
h 15883  0.42253546
i 15883  1.05420278
j 15883  0.15760482
```

Adding data to vectors is through `c`.

```
c(Sys.Date(), y)

                        a            b            c            d            e            f            g            h            i 
"2013-06-27" "1969-12-30" "1970-01-01" "1969-12-30" "1969-12-31" "1969-12-31" "1970-01-02" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1970-01-02" 
           j 
"1970-01-01"
```

To coerce to a data.frame and cbind the data, do this.

```
y <- data.frame(matrix(y, nrow = 1, dimnames = list(1, names(y))))
cbind(Sys.Date(), y)

  Sys.Date()         a          b         c        d         e         f        g        h         i         j
1 2013-06-27 0.3946908 0.09510043 0.9753345 -1.05999 -1.041331 0.5796274 0.125427 1.319828 -1.844391 0.3365856
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution of @Roman Lustrik works, I think it is simpler:

```
> y$date <- Sys.Date()
> y
          a        b         c        d          e          f          g          h          i        j
1 -1.104803 1.184856 0.9791311 1.866442 -0.3385167 0.04975147 -0.1821668 -0.7745292 -0.9261035 1.021533
        date
1 2013-06-27
```