# Convert date in format (October 12th 2018) into date in R

Tags: r, date

I have a set of dates that look like this:

```
example_dates = c("October 12th 2018","September 16th 2018","September 26th 2018")
```

Been playing around for a while but still could not figured out how to convert this into Date class in R. Does anyone know a simple solution / package to this sort problem?

Comment: Check out [Adding date to a vector of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337059/adding-date-to-a-vector-of-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding date to a vector of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337059/adding-date-to-a-vector-of-data)

Comment: After reading the post, still dont understand how to convert my example into date..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the Tidyverse solution from `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
example_dates = c("October 12th 2018","September 16th 2018","September 26th 2018")
  lubridate::mdy(example_dates)
```

Output:

```
[1] "2018-10-12" "2018-09-16" "2018-09-26"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sub` with `as.Date`:

```
example_dates = c("October 12th 2018","September 16th 2018","September 26th 2018")
example_dates <- sub("(?<= \\d{2})\\D{2}(?= \\d{4})", "", example_dates, perl=TRUE)
dates <- as.Date(example_dates, format = "%B %d %Y")
dates

[1] "2018-10-12" "2018-09-16" "2018-09-26"
```

### Demo